# Button visibil and Invisible java android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I Want to make a Button when it clicked  go invisible for some second (00:05)
Durning this time how to show. How to understand this button coming after 5 second

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CountDownTimer** for that or else you can use **Handler**.
With handler you can set 5000 milliseconds and button click it will hide and after time interval complete then again visible ,also with countdowntimer you can set time and button hide when click and set timer after finishing it will again displayed.

Comment: Handler>>
"button click it will hide and after time interval complete then again visible," ok 
Soo durning this time how to display?